# iText PdfHtml Remove White Spaces in HTML Table TD

Tags: html, css, itext, itext7, html-to-pdf

I am using itext7.pdfhtml to convert html to A4 PDF. The library works great but I am having trouble with some white spacing in the html table TD's. Please see attached screen white the white space is highlighted in yellow.

Based on the knowledge I have with CSS and HTML I adjusted some styles and html attributes, but still having white space.

[image: screen print of the PDF generated]

**What I tried so far**
I tried to adjust CSS and HTML attributes to reduce the white space, I am able to get it some extent but not fully. Programming language is c#

**What I am expecting**
I am expecting to remove white space highlighted in the image.

**Reproducible code** using link: https://itextpdf.com/demos/convert-html-css-to-pdf-free-online

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>
  #header {
    position: running(header);
  }

  #footer {
    position: running(footer);
  }

  @page {
    margin-top: 375px;
    /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 20px;
    /*padding-bottom: 0px;*/
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;

    @top-center {
      content: element(header);
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      margin-top: 40px;
      padding: 20px;
      border-bottom: none;
    }

    @bottom-center {
      content: element(footer);
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      /*padding: 20px;*/
      border-top: none;
    }
  }

  @page wide {
    size: a4 landscape;
  }

  #current-page-placeholder::before {
    content: counter(page);
  }

  #total-pages-placeholder::before {
    content: counter(pages);
  }

  table { page-break-after:auto;page-break-inside:avoid; }
  tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  thead { display:table-header-group }
  tfoot { display:table-footer-group }

  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  td, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  .pdflogo {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 300px;
  }

  .pagecountersection {
    width: 69%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .pagecountersection td {
     padding: 3px 10px;
     font-size: 12px;
  }
 
  .ship_details {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 11px;
    width:100%;
  }

  .ship_details td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
  }

  .noborder td {
    border: 0px solid #000;
  }

  .ship_header {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .ship_header td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-align: right;
  }

  .ship_notice {
    width:100%; 
    border:0px solid #000000; 
    border-spacing:0; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    width:100%; 
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 16px;
  }


  .breakbeforediv {
    page-break-before: always !important;
  }

  .nobreakdiv {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  }

  .nobreakrow table, td, th {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }

  .bg-gray {
    background: #cccccc;
  }

  .bg-gray td {
    background: #cccccc;
  }

  .breakline {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  }

  .width40 {
    width:40%;
  }

  .width60 {
    width:60%;
  }

  .width100 {
    width:100%;
  }

  .cellWithTable {
    padding: 0 !important; 
    margin: 0 !important;
  }

  .cellWithTable table{
    width: 100%;
  }

  .cellHeight {
    height: 30px !important;
    max-height: 30px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }

  .firstCell {
    border-top:none !important;
    border-left:none !important;
    border-right:none !important;
  }

  .middleCell {
    border-left:none !important;
    border-right:none !important;
  }

  .lastCell {
    border-bottom:none !important;
    border-left:none !important;
    border-right:none !important;
  }

  .onlyCell {
    border-top:none !important;
    border-bottom:none !important;
    border-left:none !important;
    border-right:none !important;
  }

  .ship_nobordernopadding td {
    border: 0px solid #000;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  
  .ship_withborder td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }  
  
 
#customerTabl  td {
    border: 0px solid #000;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
</style>

  <div class="breakline"></div>
    <table class="ship_details" style="width:100%; border:0px solid #fff;  border-spacing:0; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
       <td valign="top" class="ship_withborder"  style="width:59%"  > <!-- style="border:1px solid #000; width:59%;" -->
          <table style="width:100%; border:0px solid #fff;  border-spacing:0; border-collapse: collapse;">
             <tr>
                <td style="border:0px solid  #000000; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 5px;" align="center">
                   <strong>Test Folllow Directions</strong>
                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td style="border:0px solid  #000000; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 5px;width: 100%; padding-left:0px;">
                      <table style="width:100%; border:0px solid #fff;  border-spacing:0; border-collapse: collapse;" id="customerTabl">
                         <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="ship_nobordernopadding" style="width:49%"  > <!-- style="border:0px solid #000; width:49%; padding-left:0px;" -->
                               <table style="width:100%; border:0px solid #fff;  border-spacing:0; border-collapse: collapse;">
                               <tr>
                                  <td style="border:0px solid  #000000; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left:0px;">
                                  <strong>Customer Address:</strong>
                                  </td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                  <td style="border:0px solid  #000000; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left:0px;">
                                  Someone Something Llc Circle</br>
                                  P.O. Box 123456</br>
                                  Somecity, ST 99999-1000
                                  </td>
                               </tr>
                               </table>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" class="ship_nobordernopadding"  style="width:51%"  > <!-- style="border:0px solid #000; width:51%; padding-left:0px;" -->          
                               <table style="width:100%; border:0px solid #fff;  border-spacing:0; border-collapse: collapse;">
                               <tr>
                                  <td style="border:0px solid  #000000; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left:0px;">
                                  <strong>Alternate Address:</strong>
                                  </td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                  <td style="border:0px solid  #000000; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left:0px;">
                                  Parent Company Inc</br>
                                  ABCD Ijkhl & Mnopqrs #111111</br>
                                  1234 Middle Circle Way., Unit #1</br>
                                  <span >Suite 100<br/></span>
                                  Other City, ST 99999</br>
                                  <span >Phone: 123-456-7890<br/></span>
                                  </td>
                               </tr>
                           
                               </table>                 
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                        <tr>
                         <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2">
                            <strong>Note:</strong> Please include a copy of this document when mailing this.
                         </td>
                        </tr>                        
                      </table>                              
                </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </td>
       <td valign="top" style="max-width:200px; width:200px">
          <table style="width:100%; border:0px solid #fff;  border-spacing:0; border-collapse: collapse;">
             <tr>
                <td style="border:0px solid  #000000; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 5px;padding-left:2px;">
                   <strong>ABC/EFG/Ijkl Mnop Abcdefghijklm:</strong>
                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="word-break:break-all;">
<td  style=" border:0px solid  #000000; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 5px;padding-left:2px; width:30%">
                   Sender Name:<br/>Someone Withone Llc Circle � Wills<br/>
                   <span >Sender Number: 20000000011112</span><br/>
                   Ship Name: AB Oceson Lines<br/>
                </td>
             </tr>
     
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
    </table>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @KJ Thanks for your response. Can you please point me where I need change?

Comment: Awesome @KJ that helped little bit, I need little more space. Any more suggestions?